# Ramifications of Changing Site Regional Time Zone

Tags: calendar, events, timezone

I have inherited an SP365 (online) site, and I'm now the admin. I see that, while the time zone for our office is really **EST**, the **Regional Settings** for the site are ***PST***. My inclination is to set it correctly--time stamps from three hours prior is confusing when looking at libraries and lists!--but there is a heavily-used calendar on the site, and I don't want to screw up meeting information for people in California or Belgium.
What would be the effect on calendars if I correct the Regional Settings for the site hosting the calendar to EST? Would my stakeholders in La Jolla start seeing incorrect times? What would happen to the Calendar Events and how they're displayed?